# Question about plutus-pab

Tags: plutus

I am trying to understand `plutus-pab`. I read in the documentation that PAB will give to a wallet an unsigned and unbalanced transaction, then the wallet will balance and sign it and then will send it to the blockchain.

Let's say if I have a frontend in a browser using RESTful API to interact with PAB in my server. The user is using Daedalus wallet (I know, this part might not be possible yet).

As my understanding, the user will either create or interact with a contract instance through the RESTful API. Here is the first question, after a transaction is formed, will PAB somehow give this transaction to my wallet to sign and balance? and what exactly means "to balance a transaction"? didn't we give the parameter for the transaction already when we made the call through the RESTful API?

The second question is about the process as a whole. I don't see when we send the validator on-chain. Does the validator show up on-chain the moment we first create the contract instance through PAB? (if this contract involves a script address). This interaction basically creates the script address and send the token there, does it also send the validator script there?

Thank you so much!